# Heroku client internal error, undefined method `database_session'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, rubygems

I'm trying to pull the database from my heroku remote but get this error message.

!    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

```
Error:       undefined method `database_session' for #<Heroku::Client:0x007fba0d5a2f20> (NoMethodError)
Backtrace:   /Users/christopheprakash/.heroku/plugins/heroku-taps/lib/taps/heroku/command/db.rb:217:in `taps_client'
             /Users/christopheprakash/.heroku/plugins/heroku-taps/lib/taps/heroku/command/db.rb:64:in `pull'
             /Users/christopheprakash/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/command.rb:213:in `run'
             /Users/christopheprakash/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:28:in `start'
             /usr/local/Cellar/heroku-toolbelt/2.40.0/libexec/bin/heroku:24:in `<main>'

Command:     heroku db:pull sqlite://db/development.sqlite3
Plugins:     heroku-taps
Version:     heroku-toolbelt/3.0.0 (x86_64-darwin12.4.0) ruby/1.9.3
```

---

I downloaded the toolbelt directly from heroku and then installed the taps plugin via https://github.com/heroku/heroku-taps.git

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Edit: I've tried every variation of the command that Heroku offers and still the same error!

Comment: As I know heroku is not supporting sqlite

Comment: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/18/push_and_pull_databases_to_and_from_heroku

I used the command straight from their website

Answer (score 0):

Change your Gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Then `bundle install`, recommit and push to heroku again

Comment: Sorry, there's just not enough info in your question to be really helpful, generic errors are like that.  We really don't know what you've tried.